# How to use ajax functions right

Tags: ajax, jquery, code-injection

I have searched the Internet, but I can't find the info I'm looking for. So I'm sorry if it's a simple question or asked a miljon times.

I'm developing a website with (probably) a lot of Ajax functions. Now I'm wondering how FaceBook is doing this, for example the 'Like' button. If I use a ajax call to a page addLike.php?post_id=1, then an visitor (with evil intentions) can use this url to manipulate my db by adding random values to the post_id.

How can I prevent this? Or what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, calls to make mutation to data entries (something stored in the database, files, etc.) should never be accessible from a 'GET' HTTP request, e.g. deleting a post in a forum. That is to say, if you're adding like to a post, you should use `$.post` to perform an ajax request (supposing you're using jQuery).

And also, authentication and authorization should be done before responding to every request. Which means, if the user wanted to add like to a post, he/she should have been authenticated and also permitted to perform the specific action. Prevailing web frameworks will help you to achieve this automatically (with configurations).

And further more, you should also prevent XSS attack by data sanitization. You can google it for more details.